# SSIS daily import from XML files

Tags: xml, ssis, replication

I am looking for a best way to import data to SQL from XML file. One of the requirements is to have whole db available on destination server which means that initially, large XML files should be transferred and later only new and updated files will be transferred.
My problem is how to handle filenames. My guess is that xml files should be just increments, like tablename1.xml, tablename2.xml etc. If that is the case, what's the best case to automatically read data from new files?

Maybe my logic is completely "wrong" and there is some better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually do it:

### Option 1

Files are being put in some appointed directory. We change the name of a processed file, to omit it next time.

Create `ForEach Loop Container` and under `Enumerator Configuration` - `Files` : `*.*`, fully qualified. Inside:

1. Dummy script task, that does nothing going into:
2. Connection `Evaluation Operation: Expression`, expression: `FINDSTRING(@FileName,"processed",1) = 0`
3. Data flow, or any other task you want to perform
4. At the end: `File System Task` with Operation: `Rename File` into `"processed" + @Filename`, which will result in a `processed_tablename.xml` file.

### Option 2

Process all files from chosen location, but later move them somewhere else. Steps are very similar, in fact it only differs at step 4, there's no dummy script needed too.

Both are name-independent, that's why we prefer this approach in both comprehensive and incremental data design.

Comment: We use your Option 2. If something in the package fails, they go to a 'rejected' folder, otherwise to an 'accepted' folder.