# data transfer from Multiple Excel files to SQL table

Tags: ssis

Need to transfer data from multiple Excel files to a SQL table.
For instance there are multiple excel files in a folder such as 
1.INR_08012013.xls
2.INR_08022013.xls
3.INR_08032013.xls
Note: Look at datepart increments in the file_name.

I'm planning to create SSIS package and import data into SQL.
I know i can import one excel file at a time but i'm planning to do several at a time.
There could be many excels so i don't want to create multiple SSIS packages for this job.

I want to create one SSIS package(for multiple excel files) and import the data into SQL.
Is this possible thru SSIS, Give me some guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an SSIS user, but using google I found

http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2007/08/loading-multiple-excel-files-with-ssis.html

and

http://codejotter.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/importing-multiple-text-files-using-ssis/

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Is the amount constant or you will have an excel for each date?

Take a look at my answer for [Daily Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211535/ssis-daily-import-from-xml-files/18213860#18213860), it's very similar to your problem.
Use variable from foreach loop as `Excel Data Source` -> `Expressions` -> `Source`.